# mysql content as column names

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a table with the contents and columns like in the picture (left side), but I want to display it on my website page with format like in picture (right).

I've tried various combinations of php and mysql syntax but still can not display them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  'NAMA',
  'TEMPAT LAHIR',
  COUNT(PENDIDIKAN) AS Jumlah
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  'TEMPAT LAHIR'
ORDER BY
  NAMA,
  'TEMPAT LAHIR'
```

[image]

Comment: *"I've tried various combinations of php and mysql syntax but still can not display them."* - I don't see an php attempt.

Comment: Since you don't actually have Nama in your output table, you can just select PENDIDIKAN from your table and group them by tempat lahir, if I understood correctly.

Comment: i posted an answer for you see if that helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.

```
SELECT `TEMPAT LAHIR`, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (PENDIDIKAN = 'S1') THEN PENDIDIKAN ELSE NULL END) AS S1, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (PENDIDIKAN = 'S2') THEN PENDIDIKAN ELSE NULL END) AS S2, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (PENDIDIKAN = 'SMA') THEN PENDIDIKAN ELSE NULL END) AS SMA 
FROM `table_name` 
GROUP BY `TEMPAT LAHIR`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'NAMA' in your query, but you want the 'Jumlah' column. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `TEMPAT LAHIR`,
  COUNT(`PENDIDIKAN`) AS `JumlahCount`,
  `Jumlah`
FROM
  `table_name`
GROUP BY
  `TEMPAT LAHIR`
ORDER BY
  'TEMPAT LAHIR`
```

After that a bit of PHP is needed to render it correctly. I know this answer is incomplete, but the same could be said of your question. It was just too long to put in a comment.